# Pandas Dataframe keeps earlier data when dataframe is changed according to user input

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Year        Sex    Area    Count
2015         W      Dhaka    6
2015         M      Dhaka    3
2015         W      Khulna   1
2015         M      Khulna   8
2014         M      Dhaka    13
2014         W      Dhaka    20
2014         M      Khulna   9
2014         W      Khulna   6
2013         W      Dhaka    11
2013         M      Dhaka    2
2013         W      Khulna    8
2013         M      Khulna    5
2012         M      Dhaka    12
2012         W      Dhaka    4
2012         W      Khulna    7
2012         M      Khulna    1
```

my intention is to show some data according to user input.as example, user can input a city from a dropdown list and dataframe will be built according to that citys' data.

the problem here is, suppose user selects **"Dhaka"** first and data is shown correctly.After that, when user inputs **"Khulna"**, dataframe just append the **Khulna** data to the earlier dataframe data.

But I want to keep only **Khulna** data at this time.

```
def update(event):

    chosen_option = var1.get()

    df=df_global #df_global is the dataframe with main read file

    grp_city=df
    #select data according to variables year and city
    df=df.loc[df['"Year"']<=end]
    df=df.loc[df['"Year"']>=start]
    lst1=list(grp_city['Area'].unique())
    df=df.loc[df['Area']==chosen_option]


    agg_df = df.groupby(['"Year"','Sex']).sum()
    agg_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    piv_df = agg_df.pivot(index='"Year"', columns='Sex', values='Count')
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

    piv_df.plot.bar(stacked=True,ax=ax1)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

    plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

the graph looks like this after several inputs
[image]

Is there any way to clear the whole dataframe everytime?

Comment: You've neglected to include any code, it sounds like all you want is to filter the df so how are you doing this?

Comment: added the update method I used.please have a look at it.

Comment: It is probably not the most efficient way to read in the data every time. But since you are doing that anyways, a solution would be to just put `df =None` before reading the csv data again.

Comment: Why don't you read the data once and then filter the data according to the user options?

Comment: please have a look at edited code and the output graph I put on the post

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest please have a look at edited code and the output graph I put on the post ,df=None also did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by replacing *fig = plt.figure(1)* with *fig = plt.figure()*
dataframe problem is also solved by reading the csv globally and filter that dataframe every time.